# Rails: Mark a class as NOT reloadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a few classes in lib/ which are not reloadable (due to their internal structure, its a jruby application). How can I tell rails to not reload these after each and every request?

Thanks!

Comment: In production mode it won't reload on every request, but if you are using passanger then it will start and stop RoR processes dynamicaly and then it will be loaded (but only once per process).

Comment: thanks for the hint, that's completely in my case. It's a class which is being used from a background thread which then causes a 'old class still in active tree bla bla'-exception. Interesting note: the background thread is written in java and the whole thing runs jruby, but still ruby sees that somebody still holds a reference on that class ;). cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at [this post about adding reloadability to plugins](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/28/reload-me-reload-me-not), I think what you could try doing is adding the file your class resides in to `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_once_paths`

Add something like this in *config/environments/development.rb*:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies << (Rails.root + "lib/your_class.rb").to_s
```

The trade off is that you will need to restart your `script/server` process every time you change one of the files.

Comment: Sounds perfect, will try that out tomorrow!